# Templating in a Javascript-Only Application

Tags: javascript, amd, templating, handlebars.js

I will be developing a large, AMD-based javascript application, structured with backbone.js and potentially require.js. I am doing research on the best way to go, and one thing I would like to get into using is a template library, particularly handlebars.js.

My problem here is that I want to make javascript-only modules that can be loaded and implemented on the fly, well after the application is loaded. Templates are based on HTML tags, but I don't want to include html pages after the fact.

My question is: Is it stupid, or valid practice to mock up HTML templates as strings in your javascript, and then render them? I feel like it would kill the entire point in performance alone, but I really don't know.

This is an example of what I am talking about:

```
var render = function(html, model) {
  var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(html);
  return tmpl(model);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var template = '<div class="entry">' + 
                   '<h1>{{title}}</h1>' + 
                   '<div class="body">{{body}}</div>' + 
                 '</div>';

  var model = {
    title: 'I love templating,',
    body: 'And so do you!'
  }

  template = render(template, model);
  $(document.body).append(template);

});
```

Is this terrible practice, or is there a better way to implement this in  a javascript-only application?

Comment: Any reason you want "javascript-only"?

Comment: tjameson, It's an internal application with production-intensive controls and pages, not a web-site for content browsing. From what I am aware, this is the best way to go for AMD-based endeavors. The application will have pluggable modules that can go into it much later. Someone should just be able to make a module in a single or few files of javascript and add it, without any HTML. Think GMail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template are used to separate html from javascript code.
I suggest you to look at requireJS text plugin to load your template code in an AMD environment.

Comment: Thanks and i'll check that out, but I suppose the other problem I am trying to solve is the number of files that will need to be imported for one module in that case. First of all, if you are implementing an MVC framework (backbone), you want to separate your model, view and controller files per module, then you have separate .css files per module, and now adding an .html file for templates means that one 100-line module will require 4 or 5 files to be loaded. I would rather include the template in my view class. I guess my question then is more a question of whether it is a performance tax.

Comment: If performance worry you take a look at requirejs optimizer. It inlines your scripts and assets so you can keep coding modular.